# Regex need to match decimal(14,2)

Tags: regex

I have been trying with a regex `^\d{0,12}(\.{0,1}\d{0,2})$`.

Valid matches:

```
.22
0.22
123456789012.01
123.2
123.
125
120.00
125444
123456789123.
```

Invalid match

```
1234567891232
12345678912345
```

How to restrict invalid matches as this regex is working fine for all other cases
now i have to restrict the digits before decimal to just 12, i hope now u all will get what i need.

Comment: is `123.` a valid match?

Comment: Change `\.{0,1}` to `\.`

Comment: Could you separate out/explain further what it's bringing back versus what you seek?   Also, what language are you working in as that will affect regex?

Comment: In `(.{0,1}...` the `.` matches *any character*, not just a decimal point. Escape it with a `\`, so: `(\.?...` (the `?` is a shorter way to say `{0,1}`).

Comment: The `.` is escaped, we didn't see it because of formatting. It's fixed now.

Comment: ^\d{0,12}(\.{0,1}\d{0,2})$ my regex is this

Comment: `\.{0,1}` makes the dot as optional one.

Comment: If you require the period, why do you make it optional?

Comment: now what i need is to avoid more than 12 digits i.e if someone enters 123456789123,123456789123. is absolutely perfect with me but 1234567891234,12345678912345 is wrong so pls tell

Comment: @PavneetSingh try `^\d{12}$` . It allows exactly 12 digits.

Comment: @PavneetSingh: How come `123.` a valid match?

Comment: You say the period is optional, which is not clear at all from the examples you provided. How about properly explaining your problem with words? Please update your question

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this,

```
^(?:\d{0,12}\.\d{0,2}|\d{0,12})$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/iS1tW8/3)

Comment: if i make the period as optional, it would match the invalid strings.

Comment: decimal(14,2) means u can have maximum length of digits 14 but 12 digits before decimal and 2 after decimal if u enter 13 or 14 digits without any decimal then it should be a error

Comment: bro thanks 4 help but still not working i have been testing your regex at rubular.com

Comment: post the rubular link here.